# Convenience (maven/gradle) dependency to overcome log4j's warning: "no appenders could be found for logger" and just write to console

Tags: maven, gradle, log4j

I am not looking on how to configure log4j so that it actually has an appender, but I rather wondered whether there exists a convenience library (similar to `slf4j-simple`) which basically just logs everything to console without the need to configure anything else.

Just adding that library and it logs to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing the question, I remembered, that for sl4fj there actually already is something like that, e.g. there is the [Log4j to SLF4J Adapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html) which basically routes all the log4j logging statements to SLF4J. For version 1.2 such a bridge exits also: `org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.25`

From there I can just use `slf4j-simple` or `logback-classic` and it will write to console. So for now (until someone offers me a single dependency ;-)) I will use something like the following, which does what I was looking for:

```
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25"
compile "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.25"
compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3" // or: compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25"
```

For log4j 2 it works as follows:

```
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.11.1"
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25"
compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3" // or: compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25"
```

Actually in my case I only required the following two (even though the 1.2-log4j-warning was displayed, but probably some other dependencies were already in place as well ;-)):

```
implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.11.1")
```